# Unsharpen/smoothen the boundaries of a person'r body in an image

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I've an image in which the boundaries of the person's body are so sharp. How can I unsharp/smooth them?
[image]

When you zoom in the image the edges are so sharp. And it's binary mask looks like below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, in opencv there is plenty of ways to do that.  Check this documentation https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html
Or do you want the boundries to be blurred ?

Comment: But, those methods blur the entire image. I want only boundaries to be blurred.

Comment: Maybe try make a mask of area you dont want to blur. Then blur the rest and add them ?

Comment: What I mean is you have white space, you can isolate it, then in one operation, you shrink it, in the second you enlarge it. Then you subtract bigger to smaller and on that mask on an image you make a blur.

Comment: can you please elaborate? Actually there are 2 input images, 1 original image, the other is a binary mask. I'm multiplying them to get the output image. Those sharp edges present in the mask itself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are looking for is to extend the edges of the body a little bit, to that the boundaries are not so sharp.

1) Do a dilate operation on the binary mask image.

2) Combine the dilated output with the original image.

You can adjust the level of dilation by modifying the kernels shape parameter and the kernel size